# 2 temp table mysql using union

Tags: mysql

I have made 2 temporary tables and tried to do union commands on these 2 tables, but I have found an error message:
error code: 1137
Can't reopen table: 'stock'
the following is the query that I have made:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stok;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bdp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stok AS(SELECT * from productA);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bdp AS(SELECT * from quantity);

SELECT AllSubs.kode, stok.stok,bdp.qty FROM
(SELECT kode FROM stok
UNION
SELECT kode FROM bdp) AS AllSubs
LEFT JOIN stok ON stok.kode = AllSubs.kode
LEFT JOIN bdp ON bdp.kode = AllSubs.kode
GROUP BY AllSubs.kode
```

as I mentioned above, this query appears an error message: 
Error Code: 1137
Can't reopen table: 'stok'

please your help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html):

> You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.

The workaround given in the above link to use CTEs, i.e. do this:

```
WITH stok AS (
    SELECT * from productA
),
bdp AS (
    SELECT * from quantity
)
-- your query here
```

But this requires MySQL 8+ or later.  If you are using an earlier version, then you may try just inlining the queries behind your two temp tables.  Or, you could create non temporary bona fide tables, and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer of a temporary table more than one time so  you should rewrite your query as

```
SELECT distinct AllSubs.kode
        , productA.stok
        , quantity.qty 
FROM  (
    SELECT kode FROM productA
    UNION
    SELECT kode FROM quantity
) AS AllSubs
LEFT JOIN productA ON productA.kode = AllSubs.kode
LEFT JOIN quantity ON bdp.kode = AllSubs.kode
```

and You are not using aggregation function then you should not use a group by  .. eventuually use distinct  for avoid rows  duplication.

The use of group by for not aggregated column without aggregation functions is not allowed in more recent version of mysql